# Can't select folder from assets

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I made a folder in my image assets in xcode called `weather-large` and I have a file in it that I want to access called `clouds.png`

So I try to access it this way:

```
weatherImageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "weather-large/clouds")
```

And also tried it this way:

```
weatherImageView.image = UIImage(named: "weather-large/clouds")
```

But it both doesn't work while I can access it in the root. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This folders just to group assets. Try:

```
weatherImageView.image = UIImage(named: "clouds")
```

Comment: Ah okay so I can't use the same name in the root as in folders

Comment: Yes, you can't use same names for different resources